# Rotate a video taken on an iPhone, and save it as an MP4

Tags: iphone, video, quicktime, encoding, mp4

I was recording a video on an iPhone and I had it "upside down" by mistake, meaning the camera was in the bottom-right corner rather than the top-left.

When I watch the video on my Mac in Quicktime, the orientation is fine, anyway, but when I watch it in VLC, then it is upside down. I want to fix the orientation because I want to convert the video from MOV to MP4, and this would also make it upside down (because it loses the orientation/rotation metadata that the MOV file contains, to properly orient the video).

How can I properly rotate the video so that it looks correct?

I tried a few methods already, but none worked. For instance, I tried this ([Can HandBrake flip/rotate a video?](https://superuser.com/questions/418985/can-handbrake-flip-rotate-a-video)), but that didn't work for me. I also tried this (
[video captured from iphone gets rotated when converted to .mp4 using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408542/video-captured-from-iphone-gets-rotated-when-converted-to-mp4-using-ffmpeg)
) but I got a few errors in Terminal when running the commands, like regarding experimental features, etc.

Comment: Do you by any chance have Photoshop? If I remember correctly, it is very easy to do with PS.

Comment: Photoshop does video now? Never knew that. But no, I don't have Photoshop. That would be a very expensive solution to something that seems relatively simple, at least with the right tools. Often free open source tools can do it, but I just can't get the right combination to work.

Comment: Yes, certainly not worth getting Photoshop just to work with the videos. But if you had it I know it works nicely. And yes, it does have some video functionality. Nothing incredible but something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened iMovie, and imported the upside down video (which only appears upside down in non-Apple apps, like VLC). Since iMovie is an Apple app, it is able to read the rotation metadata, so it showed the video correctly. I then simply exported the video as an MP4 from iMovie, which resulted in a video with the correct orientation.

No manual rotation was necessary in iMovie since it already was able to read that metadata, as I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

iMovie & VLC can both do it

I'm not sure VLC can export the result, but iMovie can.

There's also [RotateMyVideo](http://rotatemyvideo.net) which will do it online

iMovie from Crop...

[image]

VLC from Effects & Filters > Video Effects > Geometry > Transform

[image]

Source : http://www.wikihow.com/Rotate-a-Video

Comment: Although neither method worked for me (and a few of the ones listed on that page are Windows-only or upload-only), it reminded me of iMovie, so that helped. Thanks!